# Code splitting ReactJS component to separate API call function fails test at importing the extracted function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Here's the directory structure

```
resources/js/containers/Grid
├── Grid.js
├── getAllBlogsPreview.js
└── package.json
```

`getAllBlogsPreview` is imported in to Grid

```
import getAllBlogsPreview from "./getAllBlogsPreview";
```

is a function that calls axis and returns a result with some data.

```
export default function getAllBlogsPreview({ blogs = [], showGrid = false }) {
    Axios.get("/api/blogs")
        .then(response => {
            blogs = response.data;
            showGrid = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    let result = {
        blogs: blogs,
        showGrid: showGrid
    };
    return result;
}
```

Moved it out as it was impossible to test the Component with `componentDidMount` method and certain `refreshTable` method doing these api calls directly. So now in the component I have

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateBlogsTable();
}

updateBlogsTable() {
    let result = getAllBlogsPreview();
    this.setState({ blogs: result.blogs });
    this.setState({ showGrid: result.showGrid });
}
```

The idea is the that I should be able to mock implementation of `getAllBlogsPreview` and thereby test Grid without being stuck with resolving promises.

The test fails as it tries to load `getAllBlogsPreview` from the test file itself

```
// the component to test
import Grid from "../../containers/Grid/Grid";
import getAllBlogsPreview from "../../containers/Grid/getAllBlogsPreview";
jest.mock("getAllBlogsPreview");

    describe("Blog Grid", () => {
        const result = {
            blogs: {
                data: [
                    {
                        title: "title one",
                        published: false,
                        publish_date: null,
                        slug: "title-one"
                    }
                ],
                links: {
                    self: "link-value",
                    first: "http://adminpanel.test/api/blogs?page=1",
                    last: null,
                    prev: null,
                    next: null
                },
                meta: {
                    current_page: 1,
                    from: 1,
                    path: "http://adminpanel.test/api/blogs",
                    per_page: 20,
                    to: 2
                }
            },
            showGrid: true
        };
        const getAllBlogsPreviewSpy = getAllBlogsPreview;

        beforeEach(() => {
            getAllBlogsPreviewSpy.mockImplementation(() => result);
        });
        afterEach(() => {
            getAllBlogsPreviewSpy.mockRestore();
        });
```

The error

```
FAIL   UnitTests  resources/js/tests/Blogs/Grid.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'getAllBlogsPreview' from 'Grid.test.js'

       9 | import Grid from "../../containers/Grid/Grid";
      10 | import getAllBlogsPreview from "../../containers/Grid/getAllBlogsPreview";
    > 11 | jest.mock("getAllBlogsPreview");
         |      ^
      12 | 
      13 | describe("Blog Grid", () => {
      14 |     const result = {

      at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:276:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/Blogs/Grid.test.js:11:6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock the module, not just the name (it doesn't know the module only by that name, it needs a path):

```
jest.mock("../../containers/Grid/getAllBlogsPreview");
```

Here's a more detailed explanation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

Comment: so then the mockImplementation would be `beforeAll(() => { getAllBlogsPreview.mockImplementation(() => { return result; }); });` since I want to return data without having to deal with `Promise`